# how to apply width to css flexbox

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Rendering a list of titles and trying to give them width or flex but it's not working default width of 133px is used by tag but works on static data only min-width is working. How can I use flex or width to my tag?

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { NavLink, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "./chooseCategory.scss";
import { categoryList } from "./categoryList";
import axios from "axios";

class chooseCategory extends Component {
  state = {
    recdata: [],
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    let data = await axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`);

    this.setState({
      recdata: data.data,
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.recdata);
    return (
      <div className="chooseCategory">
        {this.state.recdata.map((title) => (
          <p className="categoryLink">{title.title}</p>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default chooseCategory;
```

```css
.chooseCategory {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  overflow: scroll;
  .categoryLink {
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `flex-shrink: 0` to `.categoryLink`.

Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-sun-elo7d?file=/src/App.js

Comment: it is same as min-width what I want is each title should take  width dynamically no extra space